# iOS Coreplot realtime data

Tags: ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

I need to dinamically update a scatterplot graph with realtime data. The data are speed (Y axis) depending on time (X axis).
As soon as I have new speed data, I add data to the datasource array then call `[graph reloadData]` to update the graph. And this is good, but how to automatically make the graph *scrolling* on x axis in order that the new data is always on screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found: need to update this property `((CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace).xRange`

Comment: you should probably mark your answer as the correct one, since it is.

Comment: I am trying to achieve same..real time graph plotting..Can you please provide your code for plotting..I really need it ..Thanks!!